# How would I go about editing the polar clock counter clockwise?

Tags: javascript, html, css

From here: http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Raphaël · Polar Clock</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo-print.css" media="print">
        <script src="raphael.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                var r = Raphael("holder", 600, 600),
                    R = 200,
                    init = true,
                    param = {stroke: "#fff", "stroke-width": 30},
                    hash = document.location.hash,
                    marksAttr = {fill: hash || "#444", stroke: "none"},
                    html = [
                        document.getElementById("h"),
                        document.getElementById("m"),
                        document.getElementById("s"),
                        document.getElementById("d"),
                        document.getElementById("mnth"),
                        document.getElementById("ampm")
                    ];
                // Custom Attribute
                r.customAttributes.arc = function (value, total, R) {
                    var alpha = 360 / total * value,
                        a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
                        x = 300 + R * Math.cos(a),
                        y = 300 - R * Math.sin(a),
                        color = "hsb(".concat(Math.round(R) / 200, ",", value / total, ", .75)"),
                        path;
                    if (total == value) {
                        path = [["M", 300, 300 - R], ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, 299.99, 300 - R]];
                    } else {
                        path = [["M", 300, 300 - R], ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]];
                    }
                    return {path: path, stroke: color};
                };

                drawMarks(R, 60);
                var sec = r.path().attr(param).attr({arc: [0, 60, R]});
                R -= 40;
                drawMarks(R, 60);
                var min = r.path().attr(param).attr({arc: [0, 60, R]});
                R -= 40;
                drawMarks(R, 12);
                var hor = r.path().attr(param).attr({arc: [0, 12, R]});
                R -= 40;
                drawMarks(R, 31);
                var day = r.path().attr(param).attr({arc: [0, 31, R]});
                R -= 40;
                drawMarks(R, 12);
                var mon = r.path().attr(param).attr({arc: [0, 12, R]});
                var pm = r.circle(300, 300, 16).attr({stroke: "none", fill: Raphael.hsb2rgb(15 / 200, 1, .75).hex});
                html[5].style.color = Raphael.hsb2rgb(15 / 200, 1, .75).hex;

                function updateVal(value, total, R, hand, id) {
                    if (total == 31) { // month
                        var d = new Date;
                        d.setDate(1);
                        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
                        d.setDate(-1);
                        total = d.getDate();
                    }
                    var color = "hsb(".concat(Math.round(R) / 200, ",", value / total, ", .75)");
                    if (init) {
                        hand.animate({arc: [value, total, R]}, 900, ">");
                    } else {
                        if (!value || value == total) {
                            value = total;
                            hand.animate({arc: [value, total, R]}, 750, "bounce", function () {
                                hand.attr({arc: [0, total, R]});
                            });
                        } else {
                            hand.animate({arc: [value, total, R]}, 750, "elastic");
                        }
                    }
                    html[id].innerHTML = (value < 10 ? "0" : "") + value;
                    html[id].style.color = Raphael.getRGB(color).hex;
                }

                function drawMarks(R, total) {
                    if (total == 31) { // month
                        var d = new Date;
                        d.setDate(1);
                        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
                        d.setDate(-1);
                        total = d.getDate();
                    }
                    var color = "hsb(".concat(Math.round(R) / 200, ", 1, .75)"),
                        out = r.set();
                    for (var value = 0; value < total; value++) {
                        var alpha = 360 / total * value,
                            a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
                            x = 300 + R * Math.cos(a),
                            y = 300 - R * Math.sin(a);
                        out.push(r.circle(x, y, 2).attr(marksAttr));
                    }
                    return out;
                }

                (function () {
                    var d = new Date,
                        am = (d.getHours() < 12),
                        h = d.getHours() % 12 || 12;
                    updateVal(d.getSeconds(), 60, 200, sec, 2);
                    updateVal(d.getMinutes(), 60, 160, min, 1);
                    updateVal(h, 12, 120, hor, 0);
                    updateVal(d.getDate(), 31, 80, day, 3);
                    updateVal(d.getMonth() + 1, 12, 40, mon, 4);
                    pm[(am ? "hide" : "show")]();
                    html[5].innerHTML = am ? "AM" : "PM";
                    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
                    init = false;
                })();
            };
        </script>
        <style media="screen">
            #holder {
                height: 600px;
                margin: -300px 0 0 -300px;
                width: 600px;
            }
            #time {
                text-align: center;
                font: 100 3em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="holder"></div>
        <div id="time">
            <span id="h"></span>:<span id="m"></span>:<span id="s"></span> <span id="ampm"></span> · <span id="d"></span>/<span id="mnth"></span>
        </div>
        <p id="copy">Demo of <a href="http://raphaeljs.com/">Raphaël</a>—JavaScript Vector Library</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

How would I go about getting only the minutes and turn it counter clockwise?

Here is a little image of what I'm taking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8rfZ.png

Would there also be a way to edit he color easily or edit the size with CSS?

Comment: There's no 'beginner', 'easy' way to do this. It will either involve tweaking the javascript, which requires some advanced js (and as I can see, mathemathics) knowledge, or creating a complicated div structure with circles, other geometric shapes and images.

Comment: That clock is weird, it just gave me the following time: `11:60:29 PM` (should be 11:00).

Comment: @bfavaretto I am experiencing issues with it too. The minute band couldn't decide where it wanted to be when the minute was (or should have been) 00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, download everything so that you can edit it.  You'll need the html source, the stylesheets, and the script file (raphael.js).  Then we can get to work.

Let's take each issue one by one.

To flip the clock, we could either edit the polar math in the onload function (which makes us have to think), or, we could use the css3 transform property (and it's browser specific aliases) with a scaleX.  I find the latter to be much more approachable and intuitive.

```
#holder svg  //apply to any elements of type svg within the element with the id 'holder'
{
    transform:scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);//for chrome and safari
    -ms-transform:scaleX(-1);//IE 9
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";//IE 8 (not sure if it also applies to 7)
}
```

Next, you want to display only the minutes.  For this, we need to delete the code that draws the other arcs.  There are two places that reference these arcs; once each in the onload (i.e. "var sec = r.path().blahblahblah") and once during the update (the calls to updateval()).  Comment out all of these lines except for the ones referring to min, since that's the minutes arc that you want to keep.  Then test and see if it works.

If you want to get rid of the little dots around the circle, you can also comment out every call to drawmarks.  Your choice; while you're testing, it might make sense to not generate those little dots.  They make scrolling through the svg source a PITA.

Hope that helps!